# Extract frames from video to a file with their timestamps as the output name

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to extract specific frames from a video and save them on an external disk with ffmpeg with the timestamp of the video as the output name, preferably with milliseconds so that I can acquire more frames per second.

As a first approach I tried to extract the frames to the external disk with the following code, where I intend to extract 1 frame per second from a specific time interval and saving them as a sequence of images.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:12:25 -to 00:12:35 -i 220718-124513_CAM0bc99448_30.mp4 -r 1  E:/images/img_%04d.png
```

Once I tried a different time interval, it began overwriting the images I had on the disk, because the sequence restarted, and the purpose of this is that I want to retrieve as many images as possible.

Then I tried the following code

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:04 -i 220718-124513_CAM0bc99448_30.mp4 -vframes 1 -f image2 -strftime 1 E:/images/"img_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.png"
```

thinking that it would give me the timestamp of the video but it saved the images with the local time, which solves the problem I was having, but I would like to specify the timestamp that those frames correspond on the video, preferably with milliseconds included, so that I can acquire even more frames per second (doing it this way, if I want 2 frames per second, it will save as one image only because the output names only cover seconds).

Finally I tried this code:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:00:04 -i 220718-124513_CAM0bc99448_30.mp4 -copyts -f image2 -frame_pts true -r 2 E:/images/img_%04d.png
```

and it supposedly solves the issue, and if there is no solution for the problem I mentioned, this will be the way I will implement this.

This is the first time I am posting on stack overflow, so if there is something missing on my question, please tell me and I will change.

Thanks in advance!